# When i use $(document).ready(function() my navigation doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have placed my navigation in header file i am using j query to show selected page. when i use `$(document).ready(function()` my links doesn't work. when i use my function without this then my function doesn't work.

```
// js code
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li a").click(function() {
        var p = $(this).parents("ul");
        $("li", p).removeClass("subtab-selected").addClass("subtab-notselected");
        $(this).parent().addClass("subtab-selected");
        return false;
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li class="subtab-selected"><a href="index.jsp">Home</a></li>
        <li class="subtab-notselected"><a href="About.jsp">About Me</a></li>
        <li class="subtab-notselected"><a href="#">Shows</a></li>
        <li class="subtab-notselected"><a href="#">Video Gallery</a></li>
        <li class="subtab-notselected"><a href="PictureGallery.jsp">Picture Gallery</a></li>
        <li class="subtab-notselected"><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li class="subtab-notselected"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
li.subtab-selected {
    background:black;
width:134px;
    font-weight:bold;
color:#fff;
text-shadow:none;
    }
```

Comment: post you html code too

Comment: Your question is kinda confusing. So, it doesn't work, both with and without `$(document).ready(function()`? With that in mind, why do you think `$(document).ready(function()` has anything to do with it? why even mention it?

Comment: with this my links doesn't work. and without this my jquery doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean by your links don't work. That's extemely vague. As it is, your code SHOULD make the links do nothing other than change classes due to the fact that it returns false. If that's what's happening, then your links are infact working exactly the way you coded for them to.

Comment: If you in fact wanted the links to be followed (thus causing a page change) the event you have bound to them won't actually do anything useful.

Comment: I mean i can't redirect to another page.

Comment: return false keeps the default action from occurring.  Don't return false if you want the link to do what is supposed to do.

Comment: @Waqarahmad see updated answer below for a demo - if that is not what you want, you need to be much more clear in your question.

Comment: What do you mean by 'what will i do?'

Comment: You are saying that do not return false, what will do in this place return True

Comment: Thanks every one done my job with another function by reading url of the page

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is, when you were not using the `ready` function, that code was never running so the links worked fine, now you have added the `ready` function the function is being called and is returning `false` which will prevent the link from working. so I recommend you remove that. like so.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li a").click(function() {
        var p = $(this).parents("ul");
        $("li", p).removeClass("subtab-selected").addClass("subtab-notselected");
        $(this).parent().addClass("subtab-selected");
        // return false;
    });
});
```

Although that still doesn't make sense to me...

Here I have assumed that **Links don't work** means that your links are not taking you where you wan't to go, if that isn't the case you need to define **links don't work**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if your links are added dynamically after the document is loaded

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("li a").on('click',function() {
        var p = $(this).parents("ul");
        $("li", p).removeClass("subtab-selected").addClass("subtab-notselected");
        $(this).parent().addClass("subtab-selected");
        return false;
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are building your page/adding links dynamically, you either need to bind the new links as they are added or, better, use event delegation to listen for the events:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on("click","li a").on('click',function() {
    var p = $(this).parents("ul");
    $("li", p).removeClass("subtab-selected").addClass("subtab-notselected");
    $(this).parent().addClass("subtab-selected");
    return false;
  });
});
```

If you want some of your links to navigate to a new page while others stay on the current page you need to check what was clicked and return true/false depending on the behavior you want:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li a").click(function() {
        var p = $(this).parents("ul");

        alert($(this).attr('href'));

        // Early return true to let default navigation take place
        if($(this).attr('href') !== '#') return true;

        // Otherwise, user clicked # url        
        $("li", p).removeClass("subtab-selected").addClass("subtab-notselected");
        $(this).parent().addClass("subtab-selected");

        return false;
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WN7YM/1/)

**Update from Comments below**

OP:

> I simple want to redirect index.jsp to About.jsp and jquery show that by changing about.jsp backgroud color when about.jsp is open

Suggested approach:

Then you need to have About.jsp render the page with its tab selected. You can either do that server side in About.jsp or you can pass a query param or rely on the documents location and have your script look for that and set the tabs styles. (there are other ways as well if you don't like either of those approaches)

OP's final solution was to check the path of the page on load and set the appropriate styles for the correct tab.

Comment: It works just fine: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WN7YM/) - this attaches an event handler to your code, clicks on the links hit the event handler.  Notice the alert popping up?

Comment: in this demo why **About Me** is not changing its background color

Comment: Because the logic is looking for an href === '#'.  If it doesn't find that, it lets the default navigation happen without changing anything on the page.  In this case, the browser will make a request to the server to load 'About.jsp'.  If you are attempting to make a single page app that doesn't change pages, but instead loads the result of About.aps into a new tab, that is a completely different question from what you asked above.

Comment: I simple want to redirect index.jsp to About.jsp and jquery show that by changing about.jsp backgroud color when about.jsp is open.

Comment: Then you need to have About.jsp render the page with its tab selected.  You can either do that server side in About.jsp or you can pass a query param or rely on the documents location and have your script look for that and set the tabs styles. (there are other ways as well if you don't like either of those approaches)